# Sequencer's timeline is partly transparent and is hiding my clips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

There’s a section of the video sequencer where I can see three clips as you can see in the picture but in the area marked in red there are clips but you just can’t see them. In that area where you can’t see the clips is an alpha checkerboard pattern I don’t know why that is. If I scrub the playhead over the clips in the area marked in red in the picture I could hear the clips play. Any help on this would be appreciated.

[image]

Here’s a link to my blender file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nVliEzQ4V8GCt3M7vNLme06Fqqr7ViBB/view?usp=sharing 1 I heard that you could just pack the audio files into the blend file but I wasn’t sure so I included them in the zip file)

**Edit** (by vklidu)
... just to be sure, what we are talking about ... left/right sides of sequencer's timeline has transparent background (only in place of visible strips background is solid) ... there seems to be a hidden audio strips. How can I unhide them / brings bg solid too?

[image]

Comment: i just cannot see a marked red area?

Comment: @Chris I've removed all strips and all objects from scene, but something keeps playing. I have no idea

Comment: @Crantisz ... there are hidden strips in timeline in place of  transparent background (checker raster) ... the middle part with the three strips is somehow selected, like some range ... but I also went through all setup and properties, checked internet for such thing ... and I cant find any hint for such ranging it is like some view range or what ... it is frustrating, I feels like an idiot :)

Comment: @Crantisz: i looked at it too and had no idea ;) i thought of a wrecked blend file...but i have to admit that i am not a VSE expert...i am still a beginner in that area. I can only think of a cache issue or a corrupt file ‍♂️

Comment: Looking at Outliner > Data API there is some mismatch with Screens ... there are several "Default.xxx" ... usually for Workspace - Layout the Screen is Layout and is only one ... in your file for Sequencer workspace is listed [5 Screens](https://imgur.com/Rnim62H) ... Does come your blend file from some older versions like before 3.x?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I checked the answer that was correct or I thought it was correct but hadn't tried it yet I figured it would work... it sounded logical. But what actually happened is I went back to my file none of these things that people mentioned worked.... but what did work is...  I first pressed tab to toggle the meta strip so it was a meta strip and not three files because that was necessary to do the next part I then went to the strip menu and chose unmeta strip which wouldn't have been there if I didn't press tab, and then after I did unmeta strip I pressed tab to toggle meta... and I was back to all my files and could see them all ... Not sure if that last time I pressed tab I actually toggled meta because I chose unmeta strip before,but pressing tab in either case worked .

just wanted to clarify because this is the only record of this online and it's important that as a community we make this known

Comment: No I actually had to select the menu function titled unmeta strip.... If you read my answer it says exactly what I did and it was different than what he wrote.... Thanks for contributing though :)

Answer (score 4):

The areas covered with checkers are areas not included in a meta strip. You toggle in and out of a meta strip with tab. So, in your case, press tab to return to the normal workspace:

[image]

Selecting all strips(A) and then View > Frame All the additional audio strips show up:
[image]

Comment: +1 oh my god...that's pretty embarrassing that i couldn't even press the tab key when the meta strip was unselected (!)...i still have to learn a lot with VSE...Thanks tintwotin!  ;) at least i wasn't alone wondering LOL

Comment: @BONYJOESVARiETYSHOW: please click on the checkmark left of tintwotins answer, because this IS the right answer - thank you!

Comment: +bambilion :) I would swear I tried Meta ... but clearly visible I couldn't :) Thanks @tintwotin